# Are there any risks to rooting a device?

Tags: rooting

I see lots of tutorials telling me *how* to root my phone (Motorola Droid), but none of them mention any potential "side effects."

Aside from a few relatively minor issues that seem to require rooting to fix, I'm basically happy with the phone and therefore a little leery of messing with a device that cost me a lot of money and is only a few months old.

Assuming that I'm *just* talking about rooting, and none of the typical post-root actions (like installing a custom ROM), am I taking any risks by choosing to root?

- Does it have the potential to brick the device?
- Will it void my warranty?
- Will I stop getting updates?
- Will the cops show up at my front door the next day? *(Yes, I'm being facetious.)*
- Anything else I should be aware of?

(See also: [Are there any risks to flashing a ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21042/1465))

Comment: See also [Security risks of rooting Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/security-risks-of-rooting-your-android-smartphone), which is marked as a duplicate of this, but actually isn't.

Comment: @romkyns, concur.  I am astonished on an ongoing basis about the number of people willing to install and run compiled code from a forum post without source.  Just posted this:  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83038/is-any-of-the-android-rooting-software-open-source

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Does it have the potential to brick the device?**

Although it has become relatively simple on the Droid, some methods of rooting pose more risk than others. So in short yes there is a potential.

**Will it void my warranty?**

It mostly depends on where you live and on your manufacturer (and their warranty policies). But technically this does void your warranty in most cases.

**Will I stop getting updates?**

Again this depends. Some manufacturer provide updates for rooted devices while others do not. These will usually continue to come in and may unroot your phone if you install them, or even require you to unroot manually before you can receive their updates. If you install a third party ROM, then there's nothing else to do with your original manufacturer.

**Will the cops show up at my front door the next day?**

I certainly hope not :) but if rooting involves cracking a bootloader, it could theoretically get you in legal trouble in some jurisdictions (anti-circumvention laws, etc.)

**EDIT:**  Also be aware that there are different root methods based on which current build you are running.

**EDIT:**  It may (as of May 24, 2017) prevent you from installing some apps: [Google Play can now prevent rooted users from downloading certain apps](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-play-store-apps-download-block-root-users-773824/)

Comment: re: warranty, you can just unroot if you need warranty, right?

Comment: @MGOwen Usually yes; no guarantees.

Comment: Rooting is legal in nexus according to [AnswersFactory](http://answersfactory.com/risk-rooting-android/) and [MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/illegal-root-android-jailbreak-iphone/)

Answer (score 49):

> Does it have the potential to brick the device?

Yes, it is possible to brick your phone, but should be very unlikely.  Usually there is a way out of even what seems to be a brick.

If you do not know what you are doing and want to use the ADB method (entering shell commands manually) to root your phone, then be sure to follow all of the directions exactly as listed. If you somehow brick your phone, then it does not matter how good your phone insurance is with your cell provider; if they find out you rooted or attempted to, they will not fix it.

If you do somehow brick your phone, then **do not panic.**  Try these things:

1. Post a thread to where you downloaded the root program or where the root method was posted.
2. Post to XDA under their [questions and answers section](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=456).
3. [Search the web](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=unbrick+android). Someone else has probably had the same problem as you.

It is quite possible to unbrick your phone, but it will take some time and patience to sort it out.

> Will it void my warranty?

Yes. But in most cases you can restore your phone to a condition that they'll never know that you rooted your phone.  And sometimes they do not even check to see if you rooted your phone when you return it.

> Will I stop getting updates?

Yes and no.  If you flash a rom, yes.  But most likely that rom has constant updates (such as CyanogenMod).  Also if you root and keep stock rom, you will still get OTA update notifications (but running an update will un-root your phone).

> Anything else I should be aware of?

May the force be with you.  No, really, it's a relatively painless process with a lot of these "easy one touch (un)root tools" and even then there is a plethora of guides and help from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) to guide you and troubleshoot any problems you might have.  But if you are happy with your phone just the way it is, then **don't root.**

Answer (score 31):

Rooted phones are just as secure as an unrooted phones if you never grant root permission to any apps. The problem is that if you root your phone, you're bound to give root permission (otherwise, why are you rooting your phone in the first place), and applications that you give root permission may turned out to be rogue or leak their permission to allow an untrusted applications to gain root-like permission.

Running rooted phone is safe as long as you know which app to give root access and which are not. Problem is, even assuming that you only pick trustworthy apps they still can leak permissions inadvertantly (in security parlance, this is called [confused deputy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem)), so you must really be careful when choosing trusted apps.

Comment: Is `root` one of the permissions that show up on the permissions dialog when installing an app?

Comment: @Jeff: no, it isn't one of the permissions in the permission dialog, at least not on non-rooted devices. I figure a root manager could potentially integrate root permission management into the permissions dialog, but that would most likely not be a good idea as most people had the habit of just clicking through the permission dialog without inspecting it carefully.

Answer (score 8):

Some malwares can escalate to root permissions even on a un-rooted phone. Like the one they just recently found in over 50 (popular) apps on the android market.

http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/221247/droiddream_becomes_android_market_nightmare.html

Comment: They were *copies* of popular apps, not the popular apps themselves.

Comment: By popular I meant that they have been downloaded many times. But indeed they were copies of relatively well-known apps with malware code added to them.

Comment: I didn't think any of the Android trojans so far actually bothered to escalate to root? They just asked for more permissions than that sort of app generally needs, and that gave them enough access to do all they wanted? That is after all what a classic trojan does, gets you to let it in and give it the access it wants.

Answer (score 4):

```
Does it have the potential to brick the device?
```

Yes.

```
Will it void my warranty?
```

Definitely.

```
Will I stop getting updates?
```

Yes, if you install a custom ROM.

```
Will the cops show up at my front door the next day?
```

Yes, but only if you're Chinese ;-). And even then, only if your police administration is near enough to Beijing.

And you should be aware that it is a security risk. A root user has access to the entire phone, including all of its functionality, and the memory of all running applications. A backdoor could be installed in a custom ROM. It might not even be to your disadvantage, but your phone might become part of a botnet.

Comment: This seems a little alarmist.  Most of these ROMs are open source, so any backdoors would be found quickly.  And I thought that it was very easy to root a Droid; can you point me to a link or resource about this Motorola issue so I understand whether or not it can affect my phone?

Comment: I have read it on a codeproject newsletter, don't have it anymore. I don't know anymore, but the 'destroy' part was specific to one line [latest probably] of mobile phones. (it's a kind of fuse, which PERMANENTLY disables your phone if you attemp to load a custom ROM) See here for the nearest thing to a reference: http://theunlockr.com/2010/07/14/motorola-continues-to-block-custom-roms/

Comment: @Aaronaught: I've never seen the source of one of these ROMs. Maybe I didn't look good enough. But even if I had the source, you need to compile from that source, there's no telling whether the ROM image was actually compiled from that source. Then, you've to review the entire source. Good luck with that. If you are really good, it takes you about a year. Then you've to create a gold-card, and some of these tools were closed-source, and that makes me a little bit uncertain about their FOSS motives. Just as the phone companies that don't release the drivers or digitally sign the boot ROM.

Comment: You won't brick the phone, it'll just refuse to boot until you flash a signed rom back on it. That whole "e-fuse" thing was fear mongering.

Comment: [The e-fuse doesn't brick](http://androidcommunity.com/motorola-efuse-does-prevent-unofficial-roms-but-wont-brick-your-phone-20100716/).

Comment: It needs to be clarified that there is a security risk only when you allow an application root access; applications which do not request root or where you deny it will be as safe as ever (which is to say, somewhat unsafe, since there exist exploits). The `su` binary could itself be malware too, but that's unlikely. Full answer: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/6010/9240

Answer (score 1):

TLDR Version (2017)

### Does it have the potential to brick the device?

**Yes and no**, kinda depends on the method: Installing an official rooted ROM or a setting toggle is safe. Using a script that relies on a CPU bug to crack kernel security isn't.

### Will it void my warranty?

It depends on:

1. The OEM ToS (Terms of Service). Most major OEMs say you lose warranty.
2. ToS validity under the regional law. For example, in the EU a ToS claiming warranty voids upon rooting is not enforceable. They can't legally refuse your warranty because of it. But in worst case you may have to fight them in court to get it (unheard of as yet).

### Will I stop getting updates?

**50/50**, varies by OEM. In the negative case, you can often unroot then re-root the updated version. But not always.

### Cops? Other stuff?

No cops. Rooting is **not illegal**, anywhere. But:

- the play store can detect it and may prevent you from downloading certain apps, though it doesn't prevent you getting those apps elsewhere.
- apps with root permission can do more damage to your system, so beware of security threats, see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/security-risks-of-rooting-your-android-smartphone)