# Some application require 'root access', what is it, what is the risks, and how can we make it available?

Tags: applications, nexus-one, root-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device)

I download the screenshot to use on my Nexus One (N1) but it can not run and said it requires `root access`. What is it, how can I allow that and what risks/notes to take when letting them the "admin" access like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see my related questions/answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what).

In short:

- Root gives you full administrator access to your phone to do things that it normally cannot do (take screenshots, [free] wifi tethering, overclocking, etc).
- **You will void your warranty** (but you can typically unroot your phone to a previous state that makes this point moot).