# If I root my Android phone, will I lose all of my data?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, rooting

As the question title implies, if I root my Droid Incredible (or any Android phone), will I lose all of my data? I'm not interested in installing a custom ROM right now so will rooting cause me to lose my data? Also, which tool should I use to root the phone?

**Edit #1:** Based on a suggestion, I rooted my Incredible using Unrevoked, and I didn't lose any information.

Comment: Depending on how you do it you won't lose any data. Which build do you have now?

Comment: @Matt Software Information reports 3.26.605.1 as the Build number.

Comment: As a follow up to this question, I did root my Incredible using Unrevoked and didn't loose any information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: **no**

Long answer:

Rooting -- if successful -- doesn't change any of your data, it just gives you root access.

Now, if you reflash your phone's ROM -- something you can only do with root access -- then, yeah, you might lose stuff. A lot of people automatically associate rooting with switching ROMs, since rooting is required. But you can root, and then do nothing, if you want.

I'm so lazy, I rooted and installed a screenshot app; but it was **so** worth it. [Okay, not lazy -- I just don't have the need nor desire for much else, at the moment. But if I want to, *I can*.]

Caveat: anything done really, really wrong can screw things up. See: [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [Unrevoked](http://www.unrevoked.com/#inc) to root your device. I don't have a Droid Incredible, but I used this method on my Desire with no probs.

You shouldn't need to wipe your data if you aren't flashing custom ROMs. Even if you do wish to later, you won't necessarily need to wipe your data, and even if you do there are lots of options for backing up and restoring your data (especially once your device is rooted!).

Good luck.

Comment: I used Unrevoked on my Incredible. It worked. Eventually. I had to try about three or four times. I should have taken notes....

Comment: When you used Unrevoked on your Desire, did it wipe your phone? Looking at the documentation, it mentions re-imaging quite frequently which makes it sound like it's wiping my device.

Comment: @wawa no, it didn't wipe my phone. All it changed was 1) added custom recovery image, 2) Enabled root access with Super User White-list app.