# Is there any way to root JB without losing all data and settings?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, root-access

Is there any technique to root Jelly Bean (perhaps temporarily) without losing all data and settings?
The phone is Nexus S i9020 with Android 4.1.2.

The phone has a bad case of the "Lag" problem - AndroBench reports: 
Random rd 4.4 MB/s  (1127 IOPS)
Random wr 0.18 MB/s 49.86 IOPS.

I have found "LagFix" as a possible solution but it requires root.

I have no other reason for root, and would be happy to have a "temporary" root that would let me run LagFix to solve that problem, and then be back to unrooted after restarting.

I checked the suggested answer (This question already has an answer here:) [If I root my Android phone, will I lose all of my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/if-i-root-my-android-phone-will-i-lose-all-of-my-data), but it is from 2010 and recommends a tool (Unrevoked) that only supports specific phones (not including the Nexus S).

I saw [a different approach here](http://completeandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/complete-guide-to-rooting-the-nexus-s/) but it appears to be for Gingerbread 2.3.3 and prior. I'm running JB 4.1.2.

So I'm still looking for a way to root JB without losing data.

Comment: If you're running Android 4.0+: Sure, just make a Backup before you start :) [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575)

Comment: Always glad to help!

Comment: Izzy, can you confirm that the ADB backup will work to root the phone?  If I do the backup of "everything", root the phone, and then restore "everything, wouldn't it be restored to the non-rooted state it was in when I made the backup? If the ADB backup does not back up "everything", exactly what is _not_ backed up?

Comment: I wouldn't use the "backup everything" then, as that means you'd have no selective restore. Rather use some alternative frontend to create separated backup archives you then can restore separately (examples can be found in the linked question). I've never tried a "full restore", but the single-app-backups restored fine for me even across multiple devices. Still: As rooting just adds some files, a full restore shouldn't lead to "unroot". You can try, and then let us know -- so next time we can say for sure :)

Comment: This question is answered here http://android.stackexchange.com/a/3159/440

Comment: Flow - I checked the Unrevoked site, and it appears that it supports exactly 6 phones (Mostly HTC). The Nexus S is not one of them. Am I missing something?