# Please help! What should I do before unrooting?

Tags: rooting, unrooting

I accidentally deleted my Photo Album in Gallery, unfortunately I never backup any of my photos. I tried to recover my photos using Android Recovery Data Software but required rooting.

Not sure what to do, so I rooted my Galaxy Nexus using Kingo Root via computer. I successfully recovered almost 90% of my photos now and I want to get my phone back to its condition before rooting. I'm not sure what to do next as this is my first time doing rooting.

Anyone can help?
What should I do before unrooting my phone using Kingo Root to make sure I get back to the version before rooting, not to lose any data and not damage my phone?
How to safely unroot my phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I root my Android phone, will I lose all of my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/if-i-root-my-android-phone-will-i-lose-all-of-my-data)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple answer, but when I used that program, I did not lose data by unrooting. To unroot, go to Settings, and press "Unroot". You will see a "com.kingroot.kinguser has stopped" message, and your phone will reboot with its data still intact.

For more see [If I root my Android phone, will I lose all of my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/if-i-root-my-android-phone-will-i-lose-all-of-my-data?rq=1)