# Security risks of rooting your android smartphone

Tags: rooting, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device)

What are the security risks specific to rooting your android smartphone? Are there any security exploits available because you have a rooted android that are prevented on non rooted androids? Examples or links to more info would be greatly appreciated.