# What exactly is superuser.apk and su?

Tags: root-access, superuser

I've done a lot of reading into rooting of Android devices. I really want to know exactly what is going on at each step before I commit to the process.

I'm a little confused as to where the superuser.apk and su files come from. It doesn't look like they are official Google files, but rather files created by a (random) individual. That said, how safe are these files?

From research, I have a general understanding of their purpose. I was wondering if anyone knew what these files were (executables? scripts?), what they contained and how they generally work.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`su` (short for Switch User) is a binary executable. It's used by Android and other *nix based systems to allow a process to change the user account it is associated with. The reason it's important from a rooting standpoint is that `su` without any other parameters will switch to the root user, meaning that processes that require root permission for their functionality need to invoke `su` (since by default they are not being run by root).

Superuser is an Android application (.apk is an Android application package). It works as a sort of "gatekeeper" to the `su` binary. Applications which attempt to invoke `su` will be forced to route through Superuser, which will then prompt the user if it is an unknown or new application. The user then has the option of approving or denying the access to `su` and optionally having Superuser remember their decision so it can automatically apply it for subsequent calls by that app. By doing this, the only apps which are granted root permissions are ones that the user chooses.

The source of both applications is available on Github, and can be examined/audited by anyone who wishes to look at it (Superuser [here](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser), su [here](https://github.com/ChainsDD/su-binary)).

You can find further details - as well as changelogs - on [Superuser's website](http://androidsu.com/superuser/).

Other related questions on Android Enthusiasts:

- [How exactly does "root" user access/account works? Do all applications run as root on my phone after rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16367/how-exactly-does-root-user-access-account-works-do-all-applications-run-as-ro)
- [What are the security disadvantages of rooting an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/what-are-the-security-disadvantages-of-rooting-an-android-phone)
- [How do I protect my phone from malicious apps once it is rooted?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/how-do-i-protect-my-phone-from-malicious-apps-once-it-is-rooted)

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed response and links! Thanks!

Comment: Are there any alternatives/equivalents to these files for the purposes of Android rooting?

Comment: @kaspnord: No, `su` is the same file used for other linux/unix OSes, and there aren't any alternatives to that, but there might be for superuser.apk. Why do you want an alternative?

Comment: I'm just curious since these files, although blessed by the open source community, don't appear to have a standard of any sort (ie. not officially Google). So, that leads me to think that it is possible for other people to create other variants of the same files. For me personally, I want to know exactly what I'm using and putting into my device rather than rely on solutions from others where I cannot know with 100% confidence what the files contain.

Answer (score 11):

The [source code for Superuser](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser) is available on github, the main author of Superuser are Adam Shanks ([ChainsDD](https://plus.google.com/116124619152562783143/posts)) and Koushik Dutta ([koush](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts), also author of Clockwork Recovery).

Koushik Dutta explained in his blog [how Superuser.apk works](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/11/fixing-su-security-hole-on-modified.html); note that the post is from the very earliest incarnation of the Superuser app, a lot of things have changed since then and some of what was written there are no longer correct for modern superuser/su implementation, but the basics should still be the same.

Both su and Superuser can certainly be replaced by alternatives, but it wouldn't really do much as the facility that su uses (i.e. exec() and setuid() system calls) is available to any executables, given that the executable had the proper permission bits (i.e. setuid bit is set to root). At the core, su is a very simple program, it just spawns a process as another user; the real security check is done by the kernel.

So, as long as you're getting the official, unmodified su and superuser app and they're installed properly with proper permission, you don't have anything to worry about, they're open source and safe, you can verify the source code yourself at github. However, it is certainly possible to get a trojaned superuser/su binary, so make sure that wherever you're getting your superuser/su binary is trustworthy (or compile su/superuser yourself if you're truly paranoid).