# What is the difference between Superuser from ChainsDD and Superuser from ClockworkMod?

Tags: root-access, superuser

A while ago I rooted my LG Optimus Slider. The process installed [Superuser from ChainsDD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su).

Now I see that there is another [Superuser from ClockworkMod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser&feature=search_result), developed by Koush.

What is the difference between these two different versions of Superuser? I thought that Superuser had been developed by both [Adam Shanks (ChainsDD) and Koushik Dutta (koush, also author of Clockwork Recovery).](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18601/what-exactly-is-superuser-apk-and-su/18845#18845)

Superuser from ChainsDD has been giving me trouble for a while now (Slow response, crashes, etc.), and I am looking for alternatives to see if it would help.

Comment: Quick followup to my question: I have been using Superuser from ClockworkMod since April and it works great. I have found it to be much more stable then Superuser from ChainsDD and it is open source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On this question, you might want to check an article on [GetAndroidStuff](http://getandroidstuff.com/) called [Superuser vs SuperSU](http://getandroidstuff.com/superuser-vs-supersu-android-root-management-at-its-best/). Quoting:

> SuperSU improves everything about Superuser and adds more options. The free version offers faster notifications, there is possibility of disabling them for each app and a new interface, attractive and easy to handle. In addition, according to developer claims by using SuperSU you’ll enjoy higher speed from the apps that require root rights, especially on Android 4.0+. The paid version called SuperSU Pro provides the opportunity to keep root rights after a system update, which usually cancels these rights. Although the method is not guaranteed the option is very useful. We have password protection and advanced log configuration settings for each application.

You might also want to read [SuperSU Brings Better SuperUser Root Permission Management to Android](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/supersu-brings-better-superuser-root-permission-management-to-android/). Quoting from that article:

> SuperSU is basically SuperUser on steroids. According to the developer, it *“allows for advanced management of Superuser access rights for all the apps on your device that need root.”*.

#### ChainsDD versus ClockworkMod

As I initially missed you were not asking about SuperSU, but ChainsDD versus ClockworkMod: Let's take a look at [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/25/koush-releases-free-open-source-superuser-app-with-support-for-multi-user-tablet-ui-x86arm-pin-and-effort-for-apps-to-declare-root-permission/):

- Koush's SuperUser is free and Open Source
- Sources are available at [Github](https://github.com/koush/Superuser)
- it supports JellyBeans (4.2+) MultiUser (SuperSU does this as well)
- it will never have a pais version, *which would go against the whole open-source principle*
- like SuperSU, it makes use of the new `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` permission (already used by several root-apps)
- PIN Protection
- Request Timeout
- Customize notifications
- x86 and ARM support
- tablet optimized (Koush speaks of "tablet mode", so no fear it wouldn't do on a phone :)

Read more in the [linked post at AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/25/koush-releases-free-open-source-superuser-app-with-support-for-multi-user-tablet-ui-x86arm-pin-and-effort-for-apps-to-declare-root-permission/).

Comment: Thanks. I did actually find that article but it discusses SuperSU vs. Superuser. I'm curious about the two different apps (from two different developers), both named `Superuser`.

Comment: Ooops... I must have missed that... Updated my answer accordingly, sorry.

Comment: `it will never have a pai[d] version, which would go against the whole open-source principle` -- Why so? It is supposed to be [free in speech not in beer](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). Could it be that I interpreted it otherwise.

Comment: @Firelord Ask that the one on AndroidPolice – I was just quoting: *and he assured me that **there would not be a paid/premium version of Superuser,** which would go against the whole open-source principle.* (check it out for yourself if you don't believe me ;) I know there are open-source apps with paid versions on Playstore (eg. DAVDroid), others have "donation packages".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but you could check this review between SuperUser and SuperSu https://www.unlockunit.com/blog/supersu-vs-superuser-whats-difference

tldr: supersu is the better one between the two