# How can I disable root on a modded device?

Tags: security, custom-roms, root-access

Is it possible to *disable* root access to applications on an Android device again after installing modded firmware?

I would like to try Cyanogen or one of the other custom ROMs, but I'm wondering whether that poses a security risk. Do all installed applications get root access automatically, or can that be disabled?

I want to keep the Android security model the way it is or at least for applications to ask for my permission before they can access sensitive data.

Comment: Possibly related/helpful: [How do I protect my phone from malicious apps once it is rooted?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/how-do-i-protect-my-phone-from-malicious-apps-once-it-is-rooted)

Comment: Actually, another one that might help you: [Security risks of rooting your android smartphone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/security-risks-of-rooting-your-android-smartphone) (itself closed as a duplicate of [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install [SuperUser](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su) you can control which apps are allowed root access.  By default it blocks all requests and asks you what you want to do.  You can give an app access indefinitely and revoke it at any time, or allow only specific requests with a timeout.  Most rooted ROMs come with it pre-installed, including CyanogenMOD, and many rooting methods will install it for you as well.

As an alternative, you could remove the `su` binary and Busybox from your device to effectively un-root it.

Comment: *Question from [zpat](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/64735/zpat):* Where do I remove the su and busybox from exactly?