# Unrooting my device

Tags: unrooting

I rooted my device using the king root app and unrooted using king root as well my device is a titan hd e500 , I tried using root cloack , but it did not work I rooted again so I am rooted now , I resorted to downloading the first version of underworld empire from aptoide and that worked for a month but with a recent update its not possible to use older version now , when the app opens it says to install new version, I tried to may b find a way to change the older app version to the new one to make the app think its running the latest version.. Not possible. I am runing on version 4.4.2 KitKat

Comment: Not sure if that's a device dependent thing. Could you please [edit] your question once more and include your device name, the Android version it's running, the rooting method you'd used "back then", which superuser app was installed, and how you've "unrooted"?

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: @MatthewRead Related question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112004/underworld-empire-after-root

Comment: The game is Underworld empire

Comment: @ZION please check my updated answer again. The "Root Hider" list I've referenced I'm currently updating, so in a few minutes there could be some more you could try.

Comment: Also related: [How to prevent applications from discovering my phone as being Rooted](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29359/16575) and [How can I disable root on a modded device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18477/16575) (huh, @MatthewRead, remember that? :)

Comment: I really hope I can make this game work , I appreciate all the help

Comment: I tried all of the root hiding apps , no success

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154), and the real issue is that you want to play that game:

If your device is still rooted, you could install the [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/) and its [Root Cloak](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak) module, which hides root from specific apps. There might be other root-hiders as well, so it cannot hurt to search (or to check in my [Root Hider](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1021) list ;).

For more details on the *Xposed Framework* and what you can do with it, you're welcome taking a look at my [Collection of Xposed resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_xposed).

In the worst case, if you really need to unroot your device: [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) offers to do that for you. If you're using a different superuser app, there are possibilities to switch to this one. Details can be found e.g. in an article on TechRepublic: 
[Pro tip: How to unroot your Android device so you can update](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-how-to-unroot-your-android-device-so-you-can-update/) – and for the more "visual people", there's even an [Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpmzR-VfQxo) on this.

Comment: Thank you for your response , I tried root cloak with no luck

Comment: Answer updated for "worst case".

Comment: I tried all the root hiding apps , no success

Comment: Sorry, in that case I'm out of ideas (except for the unrooting via SuperSU).

Comment: Thank you for your response , I appreciated all the help