# what are the disadvantages of rooting your device

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device)

What are disadvantages of rooting device . why should it be avoided  ?

Comment: I realize this question just got migrated from StackOverflow, but this is a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device

Comment: Edited to retag. Agree with @Amanda below, duplicate.