# If I root my Asus Transformer, will I still get and install the manufacture updates?

Tags: rooting, updates, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have an Asus Eee Pad Transformer which I recently upgraded to 4.1 Jelly Bean from the manufacture.  If I were to root my device, will I still be able to get updates from the manufacture?

Its great that Asus has been so great about keeping such an old device up to date, but it makes me more apprehensive about making changes like rooting.  I need to root it to change the hardware keyboard to the dvorak layout.  I still need to find if I can even root it after I've upgraded to 4.1.

Comment: I don't know about how the hardware keyboard differs from the normal Android keyboard, but Jelly Bean does have Dvorak support out of the box. See [my post](http://dyscour.se/post/30294882772/how-to-use-dvorak-on-jelly-bean) for instructions (for stock Jelly Bean, at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you root your device you're gaining administrator access to it ([root](http://www.linfo.org/root.html)). Nothing more nothing less.

So, unless you install a third party ROM, you will continue to receive updates and be able to use the source code you [download](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=20&m=Eee%20Pad%20Transformer%20TF101). One small issue, updates may unroot your phone if you install them.

---

Some useful reading on this subject:

- [What does “to root a phone” mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236/16265)
- [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164/16265)

Comment: I understand root as my main box at home is linux.  My concern is that having root will make the updates behave poorly on accident or on purpose by the manufacture.  A friend of mine had a droidx that wouldn't update after he rooted (though now that I think about it, it might have been the bootloader that got put on when he rooted).  Sounds like generally I'll still be able to get updates from the second link you posted.

Comment: @Dan: Custom bootloader and/or recovery are the usual culprits of stopped updates.