# Rooting Asus memo pad HD 7

Tags: rooting

Can any one show me a tutorial that how can I root my Asus memo pad hd7 ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the main  [How do I root my Android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device?lq=1) from this site.

[This is a blog on rooting the device](http://unsolicitedbutoffered.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/rooting-and-installing-google-play.html#!/2013/12/rooting-and-installing-google-play.html) and installing gApps on the device (if necessary).

[This is the XDA thread on the root apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37508806&postcount=1) this should be a one click rooting process.

[This is a recovery / ROM for the device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2503668)

As always the disclaimer to this applies:

> Rooting your phone may void your carrier and manufacturer warranty. You accept all responsibility if you brick your device. If you are ever in doubt STOP! This is not something to take lightly.

[Read this also](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device?rq=1) as it relates to the risk of rooting a device.

And once more I have to emphasise: ALWAYS backup everything, all the time. Then back it up again.

Comment: And then again, for the laugh.