# Does rooting phone affect online banking security?

Tags: rooting, security, htc

I'm thinking of rooting my android phone (HTC Desire 300) and was wondering if doing so would affect the internet security with stuff like online banking. Is it still secure to do my banking on a phone that has been rooted? Does it make any of my other online passwords or details vulnerable or unsecured?

Comment: dup http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device

Comment: I agree with n00b – after taking a look at [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/6010/16575). Perfectly fits your question IMHO.

Comment: Aww thanks so much guys, sorry I'm new to this site and didn't see that thread :) thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

When your phone is "rooted", applications can be installed (intentionally or otherwise) that can do almost anything on your phone, including breaching the Android application sandbox.  Thus, by rooting your phone, you are removing a critical layer of the multi-layered security system.  This can be mitigated, to a degree, by restricting root privileges to only applications that you trust.

Typically, to obtain root privileges, you have to run code for which you don't have the source code.  This also lowers your overall security.

In the end, some people will choose to not root their phones because the risks outweigh the benefits, while others come to the opposite value-based decision.

Comment: `"the opposite value-based decision"` that's a good way of putting it! +1

Comment: Thanks for answering. Hmm that's definitely making me re-evaluate my desicion to root. This may seem like an oxymoron but is there anyway to root without the security breach?

Comment: You can try dual-boot and have one rooted and one "normal" ROM installed.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks TimoS. I will look into that :)