# What will happen if I update android apps over internet on a rooted phone on Google play store

Tags: rooting

If I update android apps over Google play store on a rooted phone will my android apps get updated or is it illegal to update or will my phone get damaged.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you think it would be illegal to update the apps on a rooted phone? (Note that legal questions, such as "Will X void my warranty?" are off-topic here.) What is the basis behind the thought that the phone will get damaged? I failed to see an issue here. There is simply no context given to us.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because legal questions are off-topic here.  For the other part of your question, see http://android.stackexchange.com/q/164/1465

Answer (score 1):

A rooted device just means that the root user has been exposed. In other words, apps and other things have the ability to access data that could be seen as sensitive or dangerous. As long as you do not give root access to untrustworthy apps, you are fine. You will not damage your device or do anything illegal.