# New Disadvantages of Rooting since 2010?

Tags: rooting

We have great [a question from 2010](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device) with some great answers about potential issues arising from rooting but newer versions of Android have become stricter about rooting and now allow apps to do some device checks.

**What new disadvantages are possible since 2010?**

From answers to the linked question, we already knew then that rooting can potentially brick a device, void its warranty and stop updates. I've also recently encountered SafetyNet which can cause an issue but have no idea what else I got myself into since rooting my phone.

Comment: Is SafetyNet not big enough? More and more apps are now relying on it, even games.

Comment: @AndyYan - It is a big one and I just discovered it after 2 days since rooting my device. It would have been nice to know, so obviously what I am wondering is what else will be an issue? Based on the times I looked something online and found *it is easy if your phone is rooted*, I was certainly sold on the benefits.